# Show UI dialog from Service.contracts project following coding rules

Tags: c#, vb.net, design-patterns, architecture

my dto's located in the contracts project, layer between UI and Service

I have an observable collection of thes objects loaded in a grid in my view.
A checkbox is binded to a boolean value of the dto.

Now i run into the situation that in certain cases if the boolean is checked i need to present the user with a dialog view to modify some properties.

I cannot create this view in my UI project cause this will cause a circular reference between the UI and Contracts projects.

I could add the view in the contract project but i don't consider this a 'clean' solution.
Same issue for creating the view in my 'Common' project, Here are the utilities used through the entire application

Any idea's how this can be implemented as proper as possible?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding a handler to the Dto's propertychanged event.
From there i can validate the object and show other views from my UI layer and i don't need to touch the Contracts project